# Calculating conditional distribution from an SEM

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, causality, structural-equation-modeling, graphical-model

Below is an example from a set of slides:

Suppose the distribution(X, Y) was entailed by the SEM:

$$X \leftarrow N_X $$
$$Y \leftarrow 6X + N_Y$$

where $N_X, N_Y \sim Normal(0,1)$ and DAG $X \rightarrow Y$.

According to the slides, the conditional distribution $X|Y=3$ is $Normal(\frac{18}{37},\frac{1}{37})$. I am having trouble deriving this conditional distribution. Below is my attempt:

Given $Y = 3$, we have
$$6X + Normal(0,1) = 3$$
$$6X \sim 3 - Normal(0,1) = 3 + Normal(0,1) = Normal(3,1)$$
Multiplying by $\frac{1}{6}$,
$$X \sim Normal(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{36})$$ given $Y = 3$, which is not the same as the solution. What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!